# Angular Universal how to find who is causing error TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have angular universal app, i build it and then i run it :

```
node dist/app/server/main.js
```

Then I get the errors :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ERROR TypeError:
>
> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

But can't see on which line it is in main.js (already built so 5k lines) so I could fix it in my app , how to debug it properly ?

Comment: are you importing any script with a `<script>` tag? Also are you using `window`, `document` or `navigator` in your code?

Comment: you can build it without the --prod flag, so that it's not minimized. Or you can go into chrome devtools to the error, and press the pretty print button, perhaps that will shine a bit of light

Comment: The error comes from node, not in the browser

Comment: @AndrėjusLazauskas and what about my question?

Comment: I built it without --prod flag and now i see everything, thanks

Comment: @AndrėjusLazauskas can you post the stack trace

Comment: @GuerricP - i use them, but i know that they can throw errors in node, but i have fixed all of them.